# Array Index Out of Bounds (Seive of Eratosthenes)

Tags: java

Is someone able to explain why I am getting an array out of bounds exception for 50 000 numbers while for 40 000 numbers the code works fine. The code is a seive of Eratosthenes algorithm for producing prime numbers.

```
public static void primeThree (int number) {

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

boolean[] p = new boolean[number + 1];

for(int i = 2; i < p.length; i++) {
  p[i] = true;
}
for(int i = 2; i < p.length; i++) {
  if (p[i] == true) {
    myList.add(i);
    for(int j = 2; j < p.length; j++) {
      if ((i * j) < number) {
        p[j * i] = false; //line number 99
      }
    }
}
}
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.err.print(endTime - startTime); //prints time taken
System.out.println(myList.toString());
```

}

Here is the error description:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147446155
>       at PrimeNumbers.primeThree(PrimeNumbers.java:99)

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147446155` screams integer overflow at me.

Comment: It would be easier to test your code if the closing brace inside the <code>/<pre> tag and code sections (open and close braces) were indented consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`50000 * 50000 = 2,500,000,000`, or 2.5 billion. Maximum java integer value is `2,147,483,647`. You are overflowing your integer value. Try using `long` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(long j = i*2; j < p.length; j += i)
    p[j] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly; -2147446155

You should never be hitting negative, right? So that means you've overflowed.

Overflow means you're using numbers too big to fit in the data type you've chosen.

You need something like a long, float, or double; int cannot handle such large numbers.

Read about the limitations of int:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Know your tools.